# testing my mnist model with my own image in pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I followed the tutorial in [geeks for geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/train-a-deep-learning-model-with-pytorch/)

I get good accuracy while testing

```
Epoch [1/10],Loss:0.1767,Validation Loss:15.1023,Accuracy:0.95,Validation Accuracy:0.95
Epoch [2/10],Loss:0.1112,Validation Loss:11.1439,Accuracy:0.97,Validation Accuracy:0.96
Epoch [3/10],Loss:0.0711,Validation Loss:8.6009,Accuracy:0.96,Validation Accuracy:0.98
Epoch [4/10],Loss:0.0606,Validation Loss:7.4755,Accuracy:0.97,Validation Accuracy:0.98
Epoch [5/10],Loss:0.0393,Validation Loss:6.7248,Accuracy:0.99,Validation Accuracy:0.99
Epoch [6/10],Loss:0.0311,Validation Loss:8.4266,Accuracy:1.00,Validation Accuracy:0.99
Epoch [7/10],Loss:0.0388,Validation Loss:6.4547,Accuracy:1.00,Validation Accuracy:0.99
Epoch [8/10],Loss:0.0216,Validation Loss:6.4336,Accuracy:1.00,Validation Accuracy:1.00
Epoch [9/10],Loss:0.0426,Validation Loss:6.8441,Accuracy:1.00,Validation Accuracy:0.98
Epoch [10/10],Loss:0.0167,Validation Loss:6.0449,Accuracy:0.99,Validation Accuracy:1.00
```

Test accuracy:

```
Test Accuracy: 99.12%
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.99      1.00      0.99       980
           1       0.99      1.00      0.99      1135
           2       0.99      0.99      0.99      1032
           3       0.99      0.99      0.99      1010
           4       0.99      0.99      0.99       982
           5       0.99      0.99      0.99       892
           6       1.00      0.99      0.99       958
           7       0.99      0.99      0.99      1028
           8       0.99      0.99      0.99       974
           9       0.99      0.98      0.99      1009

    accuracy                           0.99     10000
   macro avg       0.99      0.99      0.99     10000
weighted avg       0.99      0.99      0.99     10000
```

But when I test this model with my own image,

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import *
image = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\Sanmitha\Documents\first.jpg",0)
image = cv2.resize(image, (28,28))
batch = torch.tensor(image / 255).unsqueeze(0).float()
with torch.no_grad():
        batch = batch.to(device)
        output = model( batch )
        output = torch.argmax(output, 1)
        print(output)
```

The output is :

```
tensor([5])
```

The image is [second.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGL29.jpg)

I have one more image to test : [first.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSMVB.jpg)

In both of these images I need to detect the door numbers. The answers should be

In second.jpg : 110/50 (only numbers at least).
In first.jpg : 38/42 (only numbers at least)

I don't know how to do this job. Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

As apparent from your test images, you are not trying to solve an MNIST-like problem but rather an [SVHN](https://paperswithcode.com/dataset/svhn)-like problem. You need to use a different kind of model. The one you have trained is only able to classify digits when there is only one digit in the image; it is unable to detect multiple digits. Therefore, you need an object-detection model like YOLO. YOLO will provide you with bounding boxes for each digit in the image, allowing you to sort them by coordinates and obtain the proper order. There is a large lineage of YOLO model versions, and for some of them, pretrained weights can be found. I suggest you try to use [this code](https://github.com/chia56028/Street-View-House-Numbers-Detection#data-preparation) with pretrained model.